# Why isn't a specific array being deleted in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, arrays, splice

NodeJs: array deletion does not work. And if without a cycle, then it is deleted.

```
module.exports.run = (client, msg, args) => {
//...
//...
song_search.res.videos.forEach(async (song, i) => {
    const songInfoER = await ytdl.getInfo(song.url).catch(err => {
        const remove = song_search.res.videos.splice(i, 1); //doesn't work here!
    });
});
//...
//..
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?  Please describe exactly what you expect to happen and what you observe happening.  FYI, it does not really make sense to be removing items from an array that you are in the middle of iterating with `.forEach()`.  You can collect the indexes that you want to remove and then remove them all one at a time (starting from the end of the array) AFTER the iteration is done.

Comment: In addition, `.forEach()` is not async-aware or promise-aware so the timing of your  `.splice()` is all messed up (it happens long after the `.forEach()` loop is done and they don't all even happen in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with how you're trying to that.  The biggest one is the `.forEach()` is not promise-aware or async-aware so the `.forEach()` loop runs to completion and then sometime later, in no predictable order, your promises resolve and you try to do `.splice()` operations. Since those are done in a random order, they won't have predictable results.  In addition, `song_search.res.videos` won't have been changed when the `.forEach()` loop completes.

There are a number of ways to do this differently.  I would suggest a regular `for` loop which is promise-aware and async-aware.  Since you want to remove items from the array while iterating, it's  also easier to iterate the array backwards so removing an item doesn't change the rest of the iteration:

```
// make the containing function async
const videos = song_search.res.videos;
for (let i = videos.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    try {
        const songInfoER = await ytdl.getInfo(videos[i].url);
        // do something with songInfoER here
    } catch(e) {
        // no info for this video, remove it from the array
        videos.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
// song_search.res.videos will be updated here
```